# MS-WOPI "Save as" feature in office online word

Tags: ms-office, ms-wopi, office-online-server

Implemented PUT_RELATIVE_FILE and able to get the all `PutRelativeFile` tests passing for wopi tests.

[image]

But when I check the real document(.docx) file in WOPI office online, I couldn't get the "**Save as**" option to ***create a new file from existing one.***

[image]

[image]

What am I missing in `CheckFileInfo` response to get this option/link/button in editor/view mode.

My CheckFileInfo response information:

```
{
    BASE_FILE_NAME => stored_file.name,
    OWNER_ID => current_user.id.to_s,
    SIZE => File.size(path),
    USER_ID => current_user.email,
    VERSION => document_version(document),
    USER_CAN_WRITE => true,
    SUPPORTS_DELETE => true,
    SUPPORTS_UPDATE => true,
    SUPPORTS_LOCKS => true,
    SUPPORTS_GET_LOCK => true,
    USER_FRIENDLY_NAME => current_user.email,
    HOST_EDIT_URL => host_edit_url(request, document),
    DOWNLOAD_URL => download_url(request, document),
    "UserCanNotWriteRelative" => false,
    "SupportsFileCreation" => true
}
```

Comment: The `CheckFileInfo` looks all fine to me.